# Different Eclipse Workspaces for different courses

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I am totally new to Java and the Eclipse IDE - and not that experienced with programming generally - and I am currently enrolled with two online uni courses, both of which use Java (Algorithms 1, Stanford and Introduction to SAP HANA Cloud Platform).

I have already created the SAP workspace, and left the 'always use' box unchecked.

Are there any issues I should be aware of if I create a different workspace for the Stanford course? Is this even an advisable thing to do?

Comment: If you do things right, there shouldn't be any issues whatsoever. I use different workspaces for my courses, and haven't had a problem beyond having to copy settings over, which isn't really that much of a pain if you copy the right folder (`.metadata`)

Comment: It's certainly an option. When I was in University (a whole 4 years ago now!) I only used a single workspace and simply had a variety of projects (appropriately named) for all the courses I was doing. The important thing is you can write and submit your work, the rest is fluff (you'll pick it up eventually through experience).

Comment: Okay, that's a great help, thanks. I didn't mention that I'm on OSX, so the .metadata folder is probably called something else (certainly can't see it in the workspace). If anyone knows which folder that is, I'd be grateful for a pointer.

Comment: I'm on OS X too, so I know for sure it's there. It's just that folders (and files) prefixed with a dot are hidden by default. I did my moving through Terminal, so that wasn't an issue. You can try disabling hiding to see it in Finder if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use the same workspace, but create a separate "Working Set" for each of your courses. This way, you can share the same eclipse default settings between all your projects. A Working Set can "contain" multiple Projects, and you can decide exactly which Working Sets you want to be visible at any time (simultaneously in the same eclipse session).

On the other hand, using different Workspaces, you'd have to manually tweak all the default settings yourself every time you create a new Workspace. And if you decided to change a default setting, you'd have to manually do that to every Workspace.

Using Working Sets is much easier and more lightweight than using Workspaces. You stay in the same eclipse session when creating a Working Set or switching between them. Also, you can see and work with multiple Working Sets at the same time in the same eclipse session.

[Here is a brief article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/cleaner-workspaces-eclipse) describing how to set up Working Sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be making a lot of seperate projects I would personally make seperate workspaces, it keeps things nice and organized. I have three myself: school, android and personal.

Answer (score 0):

Very common, very standard way to maintain separate codebases when you don't want them mixing accidentally. I typically have about four workspaces on my machine reflecting different releases of the stuff I'm supporting, plus others for self-education or personal experimentation.

If the things you're working on can be guaranteed *not* to step on each other, you can of course use a single workspace instead, selectively opening and closing Projects as desired to control what's visible at any time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your personal preference but I just use the same workspace for every Eclipse installation (one per Eclipse installation). Keeping things in different workspaces definitely has it's advantages though, I just don't bother with it.

I would, however, recommend you to use a different Eclipse **installation** for every programming language you will use. Eclipse tends to get slow and in some cases buggy if you mix lots of plugins. So I have an Eclipse install for Java, one for C/C++ and one for Python/web stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely up to you, to be honest, but there are a few things to bear in mind:

- Your settings are not mirrored between workspaces
- Switching workspaces requires an Eclipse restart
- You can't open files from projects in different workspaces (i.e., you can't just quickly look at code you wrote for a different course to solve a problem you're facing on the current course)

If you're only looking for a simple way of organising Java projects, I would suggest using *working sets* within a single workspace.  This way, you can keep projects separate but still easily flick between them without having to restart the IDE.  You can also close or even remove (not from disk, just from Eclipse) individual projects as you wish if things do begin to get a bit cluttered.